# using boost math constants in constexpr

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, constexpr

Is is possible to use boost math constants in constexpr?

For example, the following line:

```
static constexpr double SEC3 = static_cast<double>(45)/180*boost::math::double_constants::pi;
```

gives me error

```
Error - constexpr variable 'SEC3' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

But if I replace the boost code with simple M_PI, it works fine.

Comment: Works on `gcc 4.8.2`. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thats surprising... I'm compiling with Clang 3.4. With gcc, it works fine.

Comment: @pmr It is a [gcc bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR57979) apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this may be the reason. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72bf75bb2175f58) gives this error:

```
clang++ -std=c++1y -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

/usr/local/include/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp:248:52: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_DEFINE_MATH_CONSTANT'

   namespace double_constants{ static const double name = x; } \
```

If it's defined as `const` and not `constexpr`, that may be why it's rejecting the code. To reassure ourselves that is the source of the issue, we can reproduce the error with this testcase:

```
// This code fails
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
namespace double_constants{ static const double name = 25; }

static constexpr double SEC3 = static_cast<double>(45)/180*double_constants::name;
```

So how do we fix this? Don't use the [non-templated version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/tutorial/non_templ.html). Boost provides a [templated version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/tutorial/templ.html) that we can use instead.

```
static constexpr double SEC3 = static_cast<double>(45)/180*boost::math::constants::pi<double>();
```

clang 3.5 also implements variable templates with C++1y mode:

```
template <class T>
static constexpr T SEC3 = static_cast<T>(45)/180*boost::math::constants::pi<T>();

int main()
{
    std::cout << SEC3<double>;
}
```

Comment: hmm, it seems the CUDA nvcc.exe does not agree with using the templated version "error: function call must have a constant value in a constant expression"

Answer (score 1):

I saw this post when I was looking for the cleanest way to define pi as a constexpr double using the boost library.  The following code snippet works well for me in Visual Studio 2017 using boost 1_66_0:

```
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
constexpr double pi = boost::math::constants::pi<double>();
```